# Managed bean method still invoked when commenting out a JSF tag using HTML comments

Tags: jsf-2, html

I'm developing a web application in Java EE 7 using JSF 2.0 which is deployed on a GlassFish 4 server.

I've created a page that contained JSF tags and after a while decided to comment out a `commandLink` that had a call to a managed bean method using `<!-- -->`

I found that this method will execute regardless of the comment.

Is this a normal behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It makes actually completely sense: HTML comments outcomment HTML code, not server side code which generates HTML code.

Comment: @BalusC Actually, I've expected that the commented code will be ignored by all parties involved. At least I've learned something new :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set flag to skip comments:

`<context-param><param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>`

otherwise will your code in comments executed regardless of comment tag

Comment: This Facelets 1.x specific param is deprecated in Facelets 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using regular XML comment you can use `<ui:remove>` which wont fire the event of your commandButton. Moreover, everything inside `<ui:remove>` won't be put in the generated HTML.

Example :

```
<ui:remove>
    <h:commandButton ... />
</ui:remove>
```